# In Grafana I am getting a "400 Bad Request Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server" when trying to update datasource configmaps

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana

In Grafana I notice that when I deploy a configmap that should add a datasource it makes no change and does not add the new datasource - note that the configmap is in the cluster and in the correct namespace.

If I make a change to the configmap I get the following error if I look at the logs for the grafana-sc-datasources container:
POST request sent to http://localhost:3000/api/admin/provisioning/datasources/reload. Response: 400 Bad Request Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
I assume I do not see any changes because it can not make the post request.

I played around a bit and at one point I did see changes being made/updated in the datasources:

I changed the protocol  to http under `grafana: / server: / protocol:` and I was NOT able to open the grafana website but I did notice that if I did make a change to a datasource configmap in the cluster then I would see a successful 200 message in logs of the grafana-sc-datasources container : `POST request sent to http://localhost:3000/api/admin/provisioning/datasources/reload. Response: 200 OK {"message":"Datasources config reloaded"}`.

So I assume just need to know how to get Grafana to send the POST request as https instead of http.

Can someone point me to what might be wrong and how to fix it?
Note that I am pretty new to K8s, grafana and helmcharts.

**Here is a configmap that I am trying to get to work:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jaeger-${NACKLE_ENV}-grafana-datasource
  labels:
    grafana_datasource: '1'
data:
  jaeger-datasource.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Jaeger-${NACKLE_ENV}
      type: jaeger
      access: browser
      url: http://jaeger-${NACKLE_ENV}-query.${NACKLE_ENV}.svc.cluster.local:16690
      version: 1
      basicAuth: false
```

**Here is the current Grafana values file:**

```
# use 1 replica when using a StatefulSet
# If we need more than 1 replica, then we'll have to:
# - remove the `persistence` section below
# - use an external database for all replicas to connect to (refer to Grafana Helm chart docs)
replicas: 1

image:
  pullSecrets:
    - docker-hub

affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 1
      preference:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType
          operator: In
          values:
          - ON_DEMAND

persistence:
  enabled: true
  type: statefulset
  storageClassName: biw-durable-gp2

podDisruptionBudget:
  maxUnavailable: 1

admin:
  existingSecret: grafana

sidecar:
  datasources:
    enabled: true
    label: grafana_datasource
  dashboards:
    enabled: true
    label: grafana_dashboard
    labelValue: 1
dashboardProviders:
  dashboardproviders.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    providers:
    - name: 'default'
      orgId: 1
      folder: ''
      type: file
      disableDeletion: false
      editable: true
      options:
        path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/default

dashboards:
  default:
    node-exporter:
      gnetId: 1860
      revision: 23
      datasource: Prometheus
    core-dns:
      gnetId: 12539
      revision: 5
      datasource: Prometheus
    fluentd:
      gnetId: 7752
      revision: 6
      datasource: Prometheus

ingress:
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: '/api/health'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    # Redirect to HTTPS at the ALB
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: grafana
      port:
        number: 80


livenessProbe: { "httpGet": { "path": "/api/health", "port": 3000, "scheme": "HTTPS" }, "initialDelaySeconds": 60, "timeoutSeconds": 30, "failureThreshold": 10 }
readinessProbe: { "httpGet": { "path": "/api/health", "port": 3000, "scheme": "HTTPS" } }

service:
  type: NodePort
  name: grafana
  rolePrefix: app-role
  env: eks-test

serviceAccount:
  name: grafana
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: ""

pod:
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: grafana 

grafana.ini:
  server:
    # don't use enforce_domain - it causes an infinite redirect in our setup
    # enforce_domain: true
    enable_gzip: true
    # NOTE - if I set the protocol to http I do see it make changes to datasources but I can not see the website 
    protocol: https
    cert_file: /biw-cert/domain.crt
    cert_key: /biw-cert/domain.key
  users:
    auto_assign_org_role: Editor
  # https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.5/auth/gitlab/
  auth.gitlab:
    enabled: true
    allow_sign_up: true
    org_role: Editor
    scopes: read_api
    auth_url: https://gitlab.biw-services.com/oauth/authorize
    token_url: https://gitlab.biw-services.com/oauth/token
    api_url: https://gitlab.biw-services.com/api/v4
    allowed_groups: nackle-teams/devops

securityContext:
  fsGroup: 472
  runAsUser: 472
  runAsGroup: 472

extraConfigmapMounts:
  - name: "cert-configmap"
    mountPath: "/biw-cert"
    subPath: ""
    configMap: biw-grafana-cert
    readOnly: true
```